# Could you pass me the salt? or Could you pass the salt?

Tags: phrases

Which of the following more common?
1) Could you pass me the salt?
2) Could you pass the salt? (without "me")

What's the difference,if any?

Comment: Hopefully, they are both relatively rare compared to: *Pass the salt, **PLEASE***.

Comment: "Could you pass the salt (to me)?" = "Could you pass me the salt?"

Comment: Drop the "me" part where not necessary (where it is obvious).

Comment: @ScotM I'd be less likely to be offended by 'Could you pass me the salt' than 'Pass the salt, please' (which sounds like a demand with a token attempt at a hedge). I'd always use 'Could you pass me the salt, please', with half a question mark in my tone.

Comment: While I, across the pond and up against the other one, would find "could you pass me the salt" affected, and a bit silly (as if I might not have the strength to lift a salt shaker, or the time to do it) and would find "pass the salt, please" both direct and polite.

Comment: I agree that the polite tone is even more important than the word choice. @EdwinAshworth could have misconstrued a demanding tone from the imperative construction coupled with the ***EMPHASIS*** on please. It's been a long time, but my mother would accede to no entreaty without the "Magic Word", and the "Could you" must be clearly implied by the special interrogative tone. Etiquette is about attending to the sensibilities of others, so I am glad to know that "Could you" is the real semantic marker for my friends on the Isles across the Atlantic.

Comment: Or 'please could you pass [me] the salt'

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two questions there - "which is more common?" and "what is the difference?"

In terms of "which is the more common?", that will depend very much on what circles you move in. I am sure if you eavesdropped in many restaurants and cafés around the country you will find a wide variety not just of those two, but many other forms as well.

What is the difference? There is a general acceptance that in the absence of the subject, it is implied as one of: the speaker (me); the place of the speaker (here); the time of the speaker (now). It depends on the context as to which one of those is applicable.